# Importance of Quaternion groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

As Dihedral group is the group of symmetries of geometric object, Symmetric group is the group of permutations. what is the main idea behind Quaternion group? Why this group is so important? Any useful comment/link plz

Comment: Quarternions are intimately [linked to rotations in $\mathbb R^3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quaternion group $Q_8$ is one of the two non-abelian groups of order $8$, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuaternionGroup.html), and generalised quaternion groups are non-abelian groups of order $2^n$ for $n\ge 3$. These groups are of fundamental importance in algebra, geometry, number theory and many other topics. Just to give an easy example, consider the following result:

*Theorem:* Let $F$ be a finite field not of characteristic $2$. The $2$-Sylow subgroups of $SL_2(F)$ are generalized quaternion groups.

If you are interested in physics, see the article [The quaternion group and modern physics](http://davidsenouf.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/The-quaternion-group-and-modern-physics-Girard.pdf).

Comment: This answer is fine, but I'm not sure why the fact that $Q_8$ is the Galois group of some polynomial makes it important..

Comment: @spin: Wikipedia is advertising this fact for the Galois group, but I agree with you. So I took it out.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the group that represents the transformation between them of three unitary orthogonal vectors in the 3D space.

Comment: What? ${}{}{}{}$